# How can I determine what sort of role architecture would benefit my Window Azure application?

Tags: .net, azure, architecture, azure-sql-database

What architectural considerations should I make when developing Windows Azure solution designed as a silverlight frontend to a dataservice backed by SQLAzure?

In short, I have a Silverlight interface that needs to get at information stored in an SQL Azure Database.  I am not sure where to draw the boundaries here, should the client be making SQL requests? If not then should that be a compute role? Would a worker role be useful here? How can I secure my communications so that I don't expose users to any secrets?

I am very new to web development, but I choose Silverlight due to my WPF background and my need to get this project rolling quickly.  I will likely go back and move to HTML5 + JS later, so please don't focus on the client end of this in your answers.

Comment: I know you asked not to focus on the client but if you are new to web development then why not learn a tool that is not on the way out.  Do you users of the app have SilverLight installed?  Are you hosting the web site in Azure?

Comment: Yes I am hosting the site in azure, and I specifically wanted to avoid the topic because it's irrelevant.  I can take 12 weeks getting the site up and running in HTML + JS or 3 weeks in SL and HIT MY TIME WINDOW.  HTML + JS isn't an option until I go live.

Comment: I know it's going to take me at least 12 weeks with HTML5 just to learn it to the level I can work with SL.  90% of my app is client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest and most supported way is the following:

Have Silverlight client communicate to your WCF RIA services hosted in an Azure Web Role. WCF services would in turn communicate with SQL Azure.

You can hit up numerous articles/tutorials on the web about how to create Silverlight clients and have them talk to WCF RIA services

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707351(v=vs.91).aspx